# Trained models for tensorflow ocr

Tags: tensorflow, ocr, image-recognition, pre-trained-model

I start the course of tensorflow in udacity, and simultaneously I am looking on the web for the topic.

I suppose that the typical use cases are well solved already, in a better way that i can achieve by my own. In other words in some place exists trained models for usual cases ready to use. I found zooModels that if I undestand properly is the thing that i looking for. but I can't realize that there does not exist a ocr model published that can recognise a number in a image:

[image example](http://static.wixstatic.com/media/1caf47_8756d9328dcd470583148d69b76a078e.jpg_srz_1024_688_85_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_jpg_srz)

Do i need to train my own model? Is there a repository that i don't know?

Comment: I don't think it exists unfortunately. But you can probably adapt the street view models, for which there is already a lot already done [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/street)